Не выводятся данные в Next JS приложении через ACF плагин Wordpress
Есть приложение, где фронт написан на NextJS, а в качестве бэка использован Wordress. Для управления контентом, среди всего прочего, использован ACF плагин. В dev режиме работает все замечательно: при изменении данных в полях ACF, меняется контент на сайте. Но при запуске build данные застывают в в том виде, какими они были на момент билда и больше не меняются. В чем может быть проблема? Плагин WooCommerce в этом же приложении работает как надо.

